# Error on Compiling Android Kernel on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel, compiling, android

I am a noob here, learning to compile android kernel on ubuntu 16.04, but I always got error like this..

> /home/travarilo/android/ubertc6/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: 4: /home/travarilo/android/ubertc6/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
>   scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/empty.o' failed
>   make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 2
>   scripts/Makefile.build:443: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
>   make[1]:**  [scripts/mod] Error 2
>   Makefile:508: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
>   make:  **[scripts] Error 2
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

where did I miss?
and any idea how to mix it?
thanks in advance